# Calculating Euler's Numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I've derived the finite series with binomial coefficients for Euler's numbers, as requested in John Conway's Functions of One Complex Variable, about p. 76, by deriving the expansion $\sec(z)$. But I get $E_4=61$ instead of prescribed $-61$ and get increasingly erroneous $E_{2n}$s beyond $n=2$, however the algorithm is implemented. How is the formula implemented beyond $n=2$?

Comment: Please add how you did it as we may be able to help you fix your working.

Comment: Alitzer: Kindly note that I've answered my question and posted the solution. valmarjoricastle@yahoo.com, user 150282.

Answer (score 0):

After posting, I realized, having derived expansion $\sec(z)$, the cited series with binomial coefficients is infinite, not finite. Hence one must work only from lowest- to highest-order terms, the derivation dictating $(-1)^n$ before each term. Thus, using implementation: 
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^n\binom{2n}{2k}E_{2k} + (-1)^n = 0
$$ 
$k =$ ordinal from isolated $(-1)^n$, I was able to get the values prescribed in Wikipedia's article "Euler Number," except that, calculating twice, I get $E_{12} = 2,711,765$, $E_{14} = -200,179,981$.